# PC-Lint error assigning unsigned int value to uint32_t variable

Tags: c, embedded, 32-bit, uint32-t, pc-lint

I have the following line of code:

```
uint32_t address = 0x40000000U;
```

This gives the following 3 PC-Lint errors when using the `au-misra2.lnt` configuration file:

```
"*** LINT: "D:\_SVN\LPC1788-32 Dev Kit\Bootloader--4\Loadware\source\led.c"(7, 35) Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of integer to smaller type"

"*** LINT: "D:\_SVN\LPC1788-32 Dev Kit\Bootloader--4\Loadware\source\led.c"(7, 35) Info 712: Loss of precision (initialization) (unsigned long to unsigned int)"

"*** LINT: "D:\_SVN\LPC1788-32 Dev Kit\Bootloader--4\Loadware\source\led.c"(7, 35) Warning 569: Loss of information (initialization) (31 bits to 16 bits)"
```

Changing to:

```
uint32_t address = (uint32_t)0x40000000U;
```

Results in a value of 0 being assigned.

Why would this be happening? It is for a 32 bit Cortex-M3 processor so this should be assigning an unsigned int.. to an unsigned int - I cannot understand why it is not acceptable.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Both cases work in `gcc`. I assume you checked that you don't have an extra `0` in your `0x40000000U` number? Does the Cortex-M3 compiler support the `uint32_t` in its header files, or did you have to define it yourself?

Comment: "Loss of information (initialization) (31 bits to 16 bits)" makes me very suspicious about your definition of "uint32_t"

Comment: It is defined in std_int.h via typedef (`unsigned int`). There are 8 hex characters in the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that PC-Lint is configured such that sizeof(int) equals 2.  You can specify the sizeof(int) to PC-Lint with the -si# option.  For example, use -si4 to specify that an int is 4 bytes.

Also, ensure that PC-Lint is using the proper include path and including the proper version of std_int.h.

Comment: I agree with you and I think this answers the lint portion.  However later in the question he mentions that casting results in 0 being assigned.  To me that indicates the compiler setting is also incorrect...

Comment: You are right - I thought that this was set by the ARM configuration file but it was not. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler may use a 16-bit instruction instead of a 32-bit to save code size. The default size for a literal is `int`, which may be only 16-bits. (I'm not sure.) The conversion error could then be from the literal itself before you cast it.

Try `uint32_t address = 0x40000000UL;`